# $\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$-equivalence versus $\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$-equivalence

Tags: nt.number-theory, invariant-theory

Let $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ be the space of binary quartic forms with real coefficients (so in particular $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ is a 5-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$), and define the twisted action of $\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ on $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ by 
$$\displaystyle \gamma \circ F(x,y) = \frac{1}{(\det \gamma)^2} F((x,y) \cdot \gamma),$$
which defines a left action of $\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ on $V_{\mathbb{R}}$. For any subring $R$ of $\mathbb{R}$, define the action of $\text{PGL}_2(R)$ on $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ analogously.

Now let $F \in V_{\mathbb{Z}}$, the subset of $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ consisting of those quartic forms with integer coefficients. Clearly, if $F, G$ are $\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$-equivalent, then they are also $\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$-equivalent. Define $n(F)$ to be the number of $\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$-equivalence classes contained in the $\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$-equivalence class of $F$. Is $n(F)$ be bounded by a slow growing function in terms of the discriminant $\Delta(F)$ of $F$?

For each prime $p$, we can define $n_p(F)$ analogously as the number of $\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$-equivalence classes which lie in the $\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$-equivalence class of $F$. Bhargava and Shankar proved that if $n_p(F) > 1$ and $p > 2$, then $p^2 | \Delta(F)$. Moreover, $n(F)$ is the product of $n_p(F)$ over all primes $p$, so it suffices to examine how wild can $n_p(F)$ be for each prime $p$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A nitpick: $V_\Bbb{R}$ is not a ring, so it doesn't make sense to talk about its subrings.

Comment: @VictorProtsak you're right, I am not sure what I had in mind. I will fix that